# How it works: transitions in Park Guides NatGeo iOS app?

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es

[Link to iTune Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/national-parks-by-national/id518426085?mt=8)

I would love to know how they do it for the transition between views when you tap on the Find button at the top right corner. I'm guessing there's some OpenGL ES involved? I'm particularly interested in these kind of animation, It'd be greatly appreciated if somebody could recommend some resources to learn how to do these kind of thing.

THanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to look in two places.

The first is the [Core Animation Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html)

This will allow you to apply rotate, scale, translate, etc transforms to your view, all in 3D. It looks like National Geographic uses a combination of them to give you the feel that the view is dropping backwards.

The second is [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It will allow you to combine multiple animations into a timeline. Normally an animation is from point A to point B but with CAKeyframeAnimations you can have multiple points that get hit at different points during your animation.

Keep in mind that bot of these are rather complicated to master so don't worry if you get stuck right away. You will eventually figure it out.

Comment: At WillCall we ended up doing something rather complicated to get just the right animation; dropping in Chipmunk and doing complete physics animation. We essentially calculate everything with Chipmunk and then build a CAKeyframeAnimation. Probably overkill but it gives you a real physics feel.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController

This is a good implementation of this effect using CAAnimation and CATransform3D

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.A viewcontroller transition inspired by NatGeo (City Guides by National Geographic) in iOS.

https://github.com/michaelhenry/MHNatGeoViewControllerTransition

Thanks,
Kel